# Импорт цены с использованием "Загрузка данных из табличного документа"

Tags: 1с

Конфигурация 1С:

- 1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.16.352)
- Управление торговлей, редакция 11.0 (11.0.8.13)

При попытке импорта цен в 1С получаю ошибку:

[image]

В обработке выбираю "Загрузка в табличную часть", создаю новый документ, сохраняю, указываю его, выбираю в "Табличная часть" - "Таблица", жму контроль, контроль проходит, жму загрузить - в логе появляются сообщения, что строка добавлена, а в конце два сообщения об ошибке - та, которая на скриншоте выше и вот эта:

[image]

Тестовые данные, на которых появляется ошибка: http://rghost.ru/40971121

Comment: Будь моя воля, я бы вообще запретил кодерам 1С называться программистами...

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что такие багрепорты надо слать в суппорт 1С. Наверное уже починили, значит просто обновиться.